# Prompt file open, make changes and save as another copy, and close + unsave the original file

Tags: vba, for-loop, save

I am trying to prompt user open file1 and file 2.
then make changes (highlight non date cell) on file 2
and then save copy of the changed file2.
At the same time, keep the original file2 unsave and close it.

Below is my code 
Running result:

file1 stays opened,

file2 is highlighted but no copy is save , and it stays open

kindly advise what is wrong with it.

```
 Sub LogSAVEAS()

 'prompt open file 1
 N = Application.GetOpenFilename _
 (Title:="Please choose file1", _
 FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls*; *.csv (*.xls*; *.csv),")
Set twb = Workbooks.Open(N)

If N = False Then
MsgBox "No file selected. Please click run again and select file", 
vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
Exit Sub
Else
End If

'prompt open file 2
R = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose file2", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls*; *.csv (*.xls*; *.csv),")
Set extwbk = Workbooks.Open(R)
If R = False Then
MsgBox "No file selected. Please click run again and select file.", 
vbExclamation, "Sorry!"
Exit Sub
Else
End If


Dim WS As Worksheet

For Each WS In extwbk.workseets 'highlight issue format cell in file2
Call highlightdate(WS)

Next


Set extwbk = ActiveWorkbook
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.copy 'copy file2 with highlight and save as "log"
dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyymmddhhmm")
ActiveWorkbook.SAVEAS Filename:=extwbk.Path & "\log" & dt & ".xlsx"

ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True 'save and close log

extwbk.Close savechanges:=False 'unsave and close file2

twb.Close savechanges:=True 'save and close file1


End Sub

Sub highlightnondate(WS As Worksheet)

With WS
  Set t = .Rows(1).Find("Date", lookat:=xlPart)

   If t Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

  For Each currentCell In Intersect(.Columns(t.Column), .UsedRange.Resize(.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1, .UsedRange.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0))
        If Not IsEmpty(currentCell) And Not IsDate(currentCell.Value) Then counter = counter + 1
     If Not IsEmpty(currentCell) And Not IsDate(currentCell.Value) Then currentCell.Interior.color = 56231
   Next currentCell

   End With


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but maybe the problem is that you close the ActiveWorkbook first?